# How to detect mongo documents with duplicate field names

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I discovered one of my mongodb documents has duplicate fields with the same key.

[image: RoboMongo Query Results]

I also realize this is supported by mongoDB (as per [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names))

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to properly query to diagnose the scope of such an issue.

And if anyone has any insight into possible root causes when working in Javascript that'd be nice too.